# Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS Nvidia Driver installation issue

Tags: drivers, nvidia, dkms

- This is something i've been trying to solve for a month. when I try
  the nvidia xserver setting it dosent open.

  when I try this command the o/p is as follows:

```
   ansel@ansel-GL63-9RCX:~$ lshw -class display

   WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.   ***-display
   UNCLAIMED**       
          description: 3D controller
          product: GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti Max-Q]
          vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
          physical id: 0
          bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
          version: a1
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          capabilities: bus_master cap_list
          configuration: latency=0
          resources: memory:a3000000-a3ffffff memory:90000000-9fffffff memory:a0000000-a1ffffff ioport:4000(size=128)
   memory:a4000000-a407ffff   *-display
          description: VGA compatible controller
          product: Intel Corporation
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 2
          bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
          version: 00
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
          configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
          resources: irq:148 memory:a2000000-a2ffffff memory:80000000-8fffffff ioport:5000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
   WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this
   program as super-user.
```

I tried downloading the latest `nvidia driver 440.82` and while
   installing it gets stuck at

```
installing dkms Kernel module Building Module 5%
```

It freezes at 5 % installation. should I turn off UEFI Secure boot or is there any other way anyone PLEASE HELP!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: What's the module version? And your kernel version? It should compile.

Comment: ansel@ansel-GL63-9RCX:~$ uname -r
5.3.0-51-generic
this is the kernel version

about the module it just shows building a new module.dosent show the version.
i'm actually new to ubuntu is there any way to check the module version